# Why does the context initialization fail for the Spring MVC tutorial section 4.6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat6

I have followed the following Spring MVC tutorial which works fine until I deploy step 4.6:
[Spring MVC step by step tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part4.html#step4.6)

The Errors I get are:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 i
n XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml] is
invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4
.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'beans'. One of '{"http://ww
w.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org
/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "htt
p://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springfra
mework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:369)
```

Comment: Post the contents of your xml file.

Comment: If you follow the link I have added the springapp-servlet.xml is there

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they are showing it like that and honestly you shouldn't be looking at a super old tutorial like that, but the solution is to simply remove the `<beans>` in

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

<beans> <---remove this guy
```

Comment: @hoaz Yup, the one that is nested.

Comment: then fix your text above XML sample